# What could cause a failure to display anything on the HDMI output?

Tags: boot, screen

Occasionally, when I power up my friendly RPi, the screen stays blank as if there is no output from the HDMI. I can still `ssh` to the device, so it is working.

Can anyone suggest reasons why it may be happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure it is just the HDMI output?  Have you tried connecting to it with ssh?

Comment: @finnw I'm sure. I'm connected to it via ssh right now and it's also connected to a blank screen.

Comment: Now it seems to have stopped working completely...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was due to incorrect settings in `/boot/config.txt`.

Actually deleting the config file solved my issue, but its purpose and possible parameters are documented [here](http://elinux.org/RPi_config.txt).

The contents of my file were:

```
hdmi_mode=19
#arm_freq=800
disable_overscan=1
```

This is what comes by default in Arch. The `hdmi_mode=19` setting sets the HDMI output to `1024x768  85Hz`, which is apparently an unsupported resolution for my monitor.

I believe that deleting the file sets the output to `hdmi_mode=1`, which is `VGA`. Clearly this is suboptimal, so I recommend experimenting to find the best value.

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility I came across is that I didn't get any display unless the HDMI cable was plugged in *before* the Pi was switched on.

Should be a relatively quick one to fault-find, but worth documenting here nonetheless.

Comment: Confirmed. This also happens.

Comment: Could this be solved by using the `hdmi_force_hotplug=1` option as documented on http://elinux.org/RPiconfig?